# Typescript: Property 'timeLog' does not exist on type 'Console'

Tags: angular, typescript, console, console.log

```
 ERROR in src/app/utils/indicator-drawer.utils.ts:119:25 - error TS2339: Property 'timeLog' does not exist on type 'Console'.

    119                 console.timeLog("drawing")
```

I am using Typescript with Angular.  When I do console.time("drawing") then console.timeEnd("drawing"), it works when I check the inspector logs of chrome. But then I use console.timeLog("drawing") and typescript dont wanna compile it.

Any idea ? (I use typescript 3.3.3333)

Comment: console.timeLog is only supported from node 10.7 and above. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Update your node types:

`npm install --save-dev @types/node`